# Count number of queries per day in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a possibility to count how many queries were executed, e.g. in a day, in Postgres 13? You could do the same with the query log I guess but I do not care which queries were executed and I would have thought that just counting the queries is more performant.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very useful metric. What would you use it for?

Comment: To calculate how much we potentially would have to pay for a managed database like aws aurora, which bills per million requests. So a ballpark figure would be nice, doesn't need to be exact.

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand what requests those are: Aurora bills for [I/O requests](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/#Database_Storage_and_I.2FOs), not queries. If you run one query per day that reads 1M pages, you'll be billed for 1M I/O requests, not one.

Comment: Oh wow this is mentioned everywhere. I don’t know how I could miss that. Do you have any idea how this metric can be estimated?

Comment: Your server OS monitoring tools and Postgres statistics collector views will tell you exactly how much I/O is going on, but mind that it will likely be very different on a managed service.